# Hide or Show multiple columns in one command

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently running the following to hide columns depending on the value of a specific cell.  It works, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to achieve this? I notice there is 2 commands hideColumn and hideColumns which suggests there's a way of hiding more than one column in a single command:

```
  resultsSheet.hideColumns(11);
  resultsSheet.hideColumns(18);
  resultsSheet.hideColumns(19);
  resultsSheet.showColumns(26);
  resultsSheet.showColumns(27);
  resultsSheet.showColumns(28);
  resultsSheet.showColumns(29);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of the following script.

  ```
    resultsSheet.hideColumns(11);
    resultsSheet.hideColumns(18);
    resultsSheet.hideColumns(19);
    resultsSheet.showColumns(26);
    resultsSheet.showColumns(27);
    resultsSheet.showColumns(28);
    resultsSheet.showColumns(29);
  ```

#### Modification points:

- When `hideColumns` and `showColumns` are used, the arguments are `columnIndex, numColumns`. In this case, when the columns you want to hide and show are continuously existing like the column "A", "B" and "C", you can achieve this using one `hideColumns` and `showColumns`. But when the columns you want to hide and show are scattered, multiple `hideColumns` and `showColumns` are required to be used.
- In this case, in order to achieve your goal using one call, I would like to propose to use the method of batchUpdate in Sheets API. When Sheets API is used, both `hideColumns` and `showColumns` can be used by one API call.

The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet you want to use. Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please set the sheet name.

```
function myFunction() {
  const hideColumns = [11, 18, 19];
  const showColumns = [26, 27, 28, 29];
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheetId = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).getSheetId();
  const requests = [];
  
  // Create requests for the hide columns.
  if (hideColumns.length > 0) {
    hideColumns.forEach(c => 
      requests.push({ updateDimensionProperties: { properties: { hiddenByUser: true }, range: { sheetId: sheetId, dimension: "COLUMNS", startIndex: c - 1, endIndex: c }, fields: "hiddenByUser" } })
    );
  }

  // Create requests for the show columns.
  if (showColumns.length > 0) {
    showColumns.forEach(c =>
      requests.push({ updateDimensionProperties: { properties: { hiddenByUser: false }, range: { sheetId: sheetId, dimension: "COLUMNS", startIndex: c - 1, endIndex: c }, fields: "hiddenByUser" } })
    );
  }

  // Request to Sheets API using the created requests.
  if (requests.length > 0) Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: requests}, ss.getId());
}
```

- In above sample script, when only `hideColumns` is declared, the columns are hidden using `hideColumns`. when only `showColumns` is declared, the columns are shown using `showColumns`. When both `hideColumns` and `showColumns` are declared, the columns are hidden and shown using `hideColumns` and `showColumns`.

  - Above process is done by one API call.
- The values of `hideColumns` and `showColumns` are from your script

#### References:

- [hideColumns(columnIndex, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hideColumns(Integer,Integer))
- [showColumns(columnIndex, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#showcolumnscolumnindex,-numcolumns)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatedimensionpropertiesrequest)

Answer (score 0):

To do this faster, you can hide and show rows in groups, with one SpreadsheetApp call required per group. For example, you can hide the seven columns listed in your code sample with this:

`hideColumns_(resultSheet, [11, 18, 19, 26, 27, 28, 29]);`

To show columns, use a similar pattern with `showColumns_()`. Here's the code:

```
/**
* Shows and hides columns that have a magic value in a given row.
*/
function showAndHideColumnsByValue() {
  const rowToWatch = 2; // 1-indexed
  const valueShow = 'show';
  const valueHide = 'hide';
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  const columnStart = sheet.getFrozenColumns() + 1;
  const showOrHideValues = sheet.getRange(rowToWatch, columnStart, 1, sheet.getLastColumn())
    .getValues()
    .flat();
  const columnsToShow = showOrHideValues
    .map((value, index) => value === valueShow ? columnStart + index : 0)
    .filter(Number);
  showColumns_(sheet, columnsToShow);
  const columnsToHide = showOrHideValues
    .map((value, index) => value === valueHide ? columnStart + index : 0)
    .filter(Number);
  hideColumns_(sheet, columnsToHide);
}

/**
* Shows columns fast by grouping them before unhiding.
*
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Sheet} sheet The sheet where to show rows.
* @param {Number[]} columnsToShow The 1-indexed column numbers of columns to show.
*/
function showColumns_(sheet, columnsToShow) {
  countConsecutives_(columnsToShow.sort((a, b) => a - b))
    .forEach(group => sheet.showColumns(group[0], group[1]));
}

/**
* Hides columns fast by grouping them before hiding.
*
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Sheet} sheet The sheet where to hide rows.
* @param {Number[]} columnsToHide The 1-indexed column numbers of columns to hide.
*/
function hideColumns_(sheet, columnsToHide) {
  countConsecutives_(columnsToHide.sort((a, b) => a - b))
    .forEach(group => sheet.hideColumns(group[0], group[1]));
}

/**
* Counts consecutive numbers in an array and returns a 2D array that
* lists the first number of each run and the count of numbers in each run.
* Duplicate values in numbers will give duplicates in result.
*
* The numbers array [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 5, 4] will get
* the result [[1, 3], [5, 1], [8, 2], [11, 3], [5, 1], [4, 1]].
*
* Typical usage:
* const runLengths = countConsecutives_(numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b));
*
* @param {Number[]} numbers The numbers to group into runs.
* @return {Number[][]} The numbers grouped into runs.
*/
function countConsecutives_(numbers) {
  return numbers.reduce(function (acc, value, index) {
    if (!index || value !== 1 + numbers[index - 1]) {
      acc.push([value]);
    }
    acc[acc.length - 1][1] = (acc[acc.length - 1][1] || 0) + 1;
    return acc;
  }, []);
}
```

This will use the minimum number of hide operations when using the SpreadsheetApp API, but it may still be slow if many of the columns are separated by other columns. The Sheets API lets you do the same with just one call — see the answer by @Tanaike in this thread.